# Is Schoons Hard Shell muskmelon a hybrid?

Tags: botany, food, ethnobiology

Would Schoon's Hard Shell muskmelon be considered a hybrid as I have read it was a cross between a Bender's Surprise and a Honey Rock.

Comment: Do you have a reference for where you read it?

Answer (score 1):

[Goldman surmises](http://books.google.com/books?id=xqG22Ah3Hx4C&lpg=PA76&dq=%22Schoon%27s%20Hard%20Shell%22&pg=PA76#v=onepage&q=%22Schoon%27s%20Hard%20Shell%22&f=false) that Schoon's Hard Shell is a variant of the Bender, so would have been bred from the Surprise, Irondequoit, and Tip Top, all of which were from the Sill's Hybrid.

In that sense, I suppose it's a hybrid. I'm guessing that you're asking because you want to know if you can save the seed; that is, if Schoon's Hard Shell will breed true or will lose its characters in subsequent generations.

I can't find any specific detail on that, but given that [it's sold by Seed Savers Exchange](http://www.seedsavers.org/onlinestore/melon/Melon-Schoons-Hard-Shell.html), I'd guess that it is a good candidate for seed saving, as long as you make sure it's not crossing with related species in your garden. [Seed to Seed](http://books.google.com/books?id=N08guuBXT5gC&lpg=PP1&dq=%22seed%20to%20seed%22&pg=PA103#v=onepage&q=%22cucumis%22&f=false) has detailed info on melon seed saving.

---

- [**Goldman A**. 2002. Melons. Artisan Books (p. 76)](http://books.google.com/books?id=xqG22Ah3Hx4C&lpg=PA76&dq=%22Schoon%27s%20Hard%20Shell%22&pg=PA76#v=onepage&q=%22Schoon%27s%20Hard%20Shell%22&f=false)
- [**Whealy K**. 2012. Seed to Seed. Chelsea Green Publishing (p. 103)](http://books.google.com/books?id=N08guuBXT5gC&lpg=PP1&dq=%22seed%20to%20seed%22&pg=PA103#v=onepage&q=%22cucumis%22&f=false)